# Running SUM across large amount of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum

I have a theoretical question which pertains to the SQL function SUM().

Imagine we have a table which contains a column called "value"

"value" is a DECIMAL number either positive or negative.

In our potential solution, we'd like to run a SUM() across all rows for column "value"

```
SELECT SUM(value) 
FROM table
```

No problems so far, but the dataset is potentially millions of rows. Possibly even hundreds of millions of rows as the data will be retained over years.

So my questions are:

1. Can you run SUM() across hundreds of millions of rows?
2. What kind of performance could I expect on a query across that many rows? We haven't settled but looking at using MySQL or SQL Server.

Comment: You might have trouble getting answer for you second question, because it is a bit opinionated and can have many valid answers (that is why those questions are not allowed). For example Column Store DBMS will be much faster at OLAP (like this aggregate) than traditional database and you "haven't settled" and thus encourage suggestions.

Comment: I see, apologies for the vague second question there and if it breaks any rules. I guess I'm interested in hearing from someone who has run SUM across that kind of dataset and can give a specific answer about query performance using SQL server or MySQL in particular. Hadn't heard of column oriented DBMS before, I'll dig on that but it may not suit for the rest of the schema.

Comment: @JoshKohlbach  . . . You can run SQL queries on SQL databases, regardless of the size of the tables (some queries might fail due to resource limitations, but `SUM()` without a `GROUP BY` is unlikely to be one of them).  You do not provide enough information to make a performance guesstimate.  But you can get free versions of databases and simply test your code on them.

Comment: in general `SELECT SUM(value) 
FROM table` would require the scan all records in the table file or all index records in the index file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look to the [column store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-2017) in `SQL Server`. In short, you are able to create a column store index on your tables - different from the traditional row store index.

These indexes are specially design for optimizing aggregate queries when huge amount of data is involved (for example, like in Data Warehouse `star` and `snowflake` schemes).

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-query-performance?view=sql-server-2017):

> Columnstore indexes can achieve up to 100x better performance on
>   analytics and data warehousing workloads and up to 10x better data
>   compression than traditional rowstore indexes.

because:

- Data compression - you can many benefits from here; for example, columnstore indexes read compressed data from disk, which means fewer bytes of data need to be read into memory;
- Column elimination - columnstore indexes skip reading in columns that are not required for the query result and further reduces I/O for query execution and therefore improves query performance (not like rowstore indexes)
- Rowgroup elimination - optimize table scans using metadata to eliminate specific rowgroups based on your filtering criteria;
- Batch Mode Execution - prior to `SQL Server 2019`, only queries involving such indexes, can benefit from `batch mode` processing which reduce your execution time further (check this [video](https://sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event18/Batch_Execution_Mode_on_the_Rowstore) to see how great is the this mode)

Comment: Based on my reading of that link you provided it sounds like a nonclustered columnstore index might be the go. Great answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may certainly run `SUM()` across an entire table, and the performance would depend roughly on how many records that table has.  Note that things like indices would not really help performance in this case, because SQL Server has to touch every record to compute the sum.

If running `SUM` on the entire table in production might not scale well, then one option to consider would be maintain the sum in a separate table.  Then, when a record gets inserted or deleted, you may use a trigger to update the running total appropriately.  This way, accessing the sum would be roughly constant time, though you would have some additional overhead because of the trigger logic.

Comment: Thanks Tim, we're considering a caching mechanism for sure to store the latest computation result, but we'd need to be running the computation in full at the time of certain transactions (to update the cache, reports, etc). My concern is on 100mil records it might take a long time. I did a pretty thorough search but I couldn't find an answer to "would depend roughly on how many records that table has"

Comment: We can't possibly know more about your table than you do.  But caching to avoid the sum query altogether seems like a good option to me.

Comment: `indices would not really help performance in this case` - this is not true - if an index on `value` column is created, then the database most probably will chose a full index scan instead of full table scan, the index scan will be much faster.

Comment: Why would an full index scan be faster than a full table scan?  Aren't the same number of values involved in both cases?  Typically an index tends to help when we want to find column values for a relatively few number of matching records, not when we want all records.

Comment: *"Why would an full index scan be faster than a full table scan? Aren't the same number of values involved in both cases?"* Yes but index files are most likely smaller then table files as faster to do disk i/o on, there are offcource cases where that is not the case.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Valid point, but it still would not be exponentially faster, which is what an index seek would provide.

Comment: *"Valid point, but it still would not be exponentially faster, which is what an index seek would provide"* Well imagine a standard HDD which can stream  ~80 Mb/s and your table file is 1GB and your index file is 100MB, it would take around 13 seconds to fetch the complete table file vs 1,25 second to scan the index file  i would call that a big difference i rather see a full index scan happening then.

Comment: *"will chose a full index scan instead of full table scan, the index scan will be much faster."* @krokodilko that assumming that the index file is always smaller then the table file, which is most likely the case in 95% of the cases.. There cases when using not much columns and covering indexes and maybe secondery indexes the index file will be in fact larger then the table file

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw out a couple of ideas.  If the data sets that you are working with are absolutely massive, consider running an overnight job to create a view, or some kind of temp table, and refer to this aggregated data blob when you get into the office in the morning.  Or, move everything to the cloud, like Azure Databricks, for instance, and run these jobs in Spark.  Spark is blazing fast and runs jobs in parallel, so everything is done super-fast.  Good luck.